# Copy paste data sequential chunks of data using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I've got a question about copying data from one excel spreadsheet to another. I want to copy chunks of data to specific cells. I will give an example with what I want to do. Let's say I want to copy data from range B3:D26 using VBA below:

```
Output.Sheets("Table6.1").Range("B3:D8").Copy
Table.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B10").PasteSpecial xlValues
Output.Sheets("Table6.1").Range("B9:D14").Copy
Table.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B18").PasteSpecial xlValues
Output.Sheets("Table6.1").Range("B15:D20").Copy
Table.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B26").PasteSpecial xlValues
Output.Sheets("Table6.1").Range("B21:D26").Copy
Table.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B34").PasteSpecial xlValues
```

I would like to automate it using loops, but I am having problems with the pasting part of it. Can't figure out what step to use. What I could come up with is below but I can't sort the pasting issue:

```
Dim i As Integer

For i =3 to 21 step 6  
Output.Sheets("Table6.1").Range(Cells(i,2), Cells(4,i+5)).Copy
Table.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(... ?? what to put there).PasteSpecial xlValues
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Sub copydata()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    j = 2

    For i = 3 To 21 Step 6
       Output.Sheets("Table6.1").Range("B" & i, "D" & i + 5).Copy
       j = j + 8
       Table.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & j).PasteSpecial xlValues
    Next i                                                                  

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks it works fine. I knew I needed to use a double loop but couldn't figure out the j=j+8 part. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the fun:

```
Sub copydata2()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim src As Range, dest As Range

    Set src = Output.Sheets("Table6.1").Range("B3:D8")
    Set dest = Table.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B10")

    For i = 0 To 3
       src.Offset(i * 6, 0).Copy
       dest.Offset(i * 8, 0).PasteSpecial xlValues
    Next i

End Sub
```